# Check current image of CCMenuItemImage?

Tags: ios, image, cocos2d-iphone

Hey currently I am trying to check the current image of a CCMenuItemImage like this:

```
if (ipodButton.normalImage == [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Image1.png"]) {
```

But the issue is, this if statement NEVER gets called. Even though I set the normal image of the CCMenuItemImage to Image1.png before in the init method.

Is there another way I should be doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will never be true:

```
ipodButton.normalImage == [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Image1.png"]
```

The reason is that you are creating a new instance of a CCSprite. This will be a different sprite than the one stored in normalImage, and thus the comparison fails because the two pointers point to different memory addresses.

Needless to say, every time this line of code is executed, a new CCSprite is created and released shortly thereafter, which wastes CPU cycles. The proper way to go about this is to use the tag property:

```
ipodButton.normalImage.tag = 10;
if (ipodButton.normalImage.tag == 10) { … }
```